# Writing to files using File System Access API fails in Electron + Create React App

Tags: reactjs, file, electron, create-react-app, file-system-access-api

I have a create-react-app that reads and writes local files using [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API). When run in a browser (Chrome or Edge that support it), both reading and writing files work fine.

When the app is run in Electron, reading works but writing fails due to: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context.`

I am using the latest Electron (12.0.1) which uses the same Chromium (89.0.4389.82) as the one in my Chrome browser.

Below is the relevant code. The console log after `requestPermission` call shows `true` and `granted` in the browser and `true` and `denied` in Electron.

I tried disabling `webSecurity` when creating `BrowserWindow`, disabling sandbox with `appendSwitch` but nothing helped.

Is there a way to give Chromium in Electron more permissions?

If not, I am willing to handle file writing differently when in Electron. In that case, what to write in place of `TODO` in the code? Note that because it is a create-react-app, the `fs` module is [not available](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3074).

```ts
export async function chooseAndReadFile() {
    const fileHandle = await window.showOpenFilePicker().then((handles) => handles[0])
    const file = await fileHandle.getFile()
    const contents = await file.text()
    return contents
}

export async function chooseAndWriteToFile(contents: string) {
    const fileHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker()

    const descriptor: FileSystemHandlePermissionDescriptor = {
        writable: true,
        mode: "readwrite"
    }
    const permissionState = await fileHandle.requestPermission(descriptor)
    console.log(window.isSecureContext)
    console.log(permissionState)

    const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable()
    await writable.write(contents)
    await writable.close()
}

let isElectron = require("is-electron")
export async function chooseAndWriteToFileUniversal(contents: string) {
    if (isElectron()) {
        // TODO: Do what???
    } else {
        chooseAndWriteToFile(contents)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question, I finally used a solution with HTML `download` attribute, nicely described [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server). When this technique is used in Electron, it presents a file save dialog which is exactly what I want. When used in a browser, this technique just downloads the file without a prompt, so I will continue using File System Access API for browser environments.

Here is the code that handles downloading when running in Electron.

```ts
function download(filename: string, contents: string) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(contents));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

let isElectron = require("is-electron");
export async function chooseAndWriteToFileUniversal(contents: string) {
    if (isElectron()) {
        download("data.txt", contents)
    } else {
        chooseAndWriteToFile(contents) // See the original question for implementation of this function
    }
}
```

Still, would be nice to know why/how is Chromium in Electron more restricted than in a normal Chrome or Edge browser, and if it can be changed.

Comment: I see there is a open electron issue for this problem: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/28422

Comment: I can confirm that calling app.commandLine.appendSwitch("enable-experimental-web-platform-features") at the start of main.js is a work around, but I would still be cautious to use this for security reasons.